# how to convert coordinate system in blender

Tags: python, system, blender, coordinate

I am writing a plugin for blender in python and I need to export rotations to a different coordinate system. I have the Euler angle but I need to convert it to another Euler in the other coordinate system.

I have tried a lot of things but I can't figure it out. I think it involves more than a simple transform because of the x-direction being flipped.

There is a picture below showing the two coordinate systems.

[image: coordinate system picture]

Comment: Add the `blender` tag to your question and improve your title to something more meaningful like "How to convert a coordinate system in Blender?"

Comment: Blender has many export addons that provide this feature, have a look at how existing exporters do it, like the [obj exporter](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/io_scene_obj/export_obj.py). The addons starting with `io_` provide import/export options.

Comment: For positions, the conversion can be accomplished simply by swapping the Y and Z values.